# How to set Min and Max date on DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to set the Min date (-12 years from now) and the Max date (+90 years from now) for my User Registration with this DatePickerDialog.

I've looked at some codes in here, but dont found how to do with my code. Just some other examples, but using diferents ways to get the date.

```
private EditText etBirthdate;    
Calendar myCalendar;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;

myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 12));

updateDatePicker();

date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
       myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
       myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
       updateDatePicker();
   }

};



etBirthdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
          .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
           myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
         }
});

private void updateDatePicker() {
        String country = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy";

        if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
            myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        etBirthdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setMaxDate` and `setMinDate` functions of DatePicker.

```
    private int pYear;
    private int pMonth;
    private int pDay;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    pYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    pMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    pDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {

        }

    };

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);

    Calendar maxValueCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxValueCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR , pYear + 90);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxValueCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

    Calendar minValueCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    minValueCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR , pYear - 12);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minValueCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    dialog.show();
```